# Scraping several pages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape through several pages of a website using Python and BeautifulSoup4. The pages differ by only a single number in their URL, so I could actually make a declaration like this:

```
theurl = "beginningofurl/" + str(counter) + "/endofurl.html"
```

The link I've been testing with is this:

And my python script is [this](http://www.worldofquotes.com/topic/Art/1/index.html).

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def category_crawler():
    ''' This function will crawl through an entire category, regardless how many pages it consists of. '''

    pager = 1

    while pager < 11:
        theurl = "http://www.worldofquotes.com/topic/Nature/"+str(pager)+"/index.html"
        thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

        for link in soup.findAll('blockquote'):
            sanitized = link.find('p').text.strip()
            spantext = link.find('a')
            writer = spantext.find('span').text
            print(sanitized)
            print(writer)
            print('---------------------------------------------------------')


        pager += 1

category_crawler()
```

So the question is: how to change the hardcoded number in the while loop into a solution that makes the script automatically recognize that it passed the last page, and then it quits automatically?

Comment: Where do you get the number of pages from? Do you know it beforehand?

Comment: I could look it up, of course, but since I want to use the script to scrape a lot of different categories in the same page, where there is a different page number in every category, I would like the script to find the last page itself.

Comment: Okay, what happens if the counter would point to a non-existing page? Would the site respond with 404?

Comment: @Gabriel: I can't really make sense of the question. Are you asking how to tell from the content of the page whether it's the last page or not (which we cannot possibly answer since we don't even know what site you're scraping), or are you asking how to stop the program running (in which case `break`, `return`, `sys.exit()` and `raise SystemError` are all possibilities depending on how you've written your code, which we also don't know)?

Comment: No, I don't know why, but instead of throwing an error, it just returns the last page's results over and over again. If it would throw an error, I could use that.

Comment: @Gabriel okay, is there a pagination block on the page which can tell which page are we on at the moment and how many pages are there?

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm sorry, I'm not native English, but I'll try to rephrase. I successfully scrape 4 pages of the site. Then the script doesn't stop, it just keeps returning the last page's data again and again forever. I'd like to use the same script to scrape more than just one category on that website, and each category has a certain number of pages. So I don't want to tell the script to stop after the 4th page in particular, instead, I want it to realize that there are no more pages in that category. Did I say it better now?

Comment: @alecxe Yes there is a pagination.

Comment: @Gabriel: sorry, your sentences were correct, that's not the problem I'm having. When I say "I can't really make sense of the question", I mean that I couldn't tell what part of it you're asking for help with. Sounds like it's figuring out whether the page is the last or not, so the problem is we know nothing about the HTML on that site and therefore don't know how to recognise the last page. But perhaps you're best ignoring me and continuing your discussion with alexcxe, whose questions I think will lead to some suggestions.

Comment: @Gabriel could you edit the question and either provide a link to the target site, or, at least, the HTML representation of the pagination block? Thanks.

Comment: @SteveJessop Okay. I need help with how to make my script realize that there are no more pages left to scrape, and then make it stop, without actually giving it a hard-coded number where it stops.

Comment: Okay, I'll update with links and my script.

Comment: How's it looking now? Better? :)

Comment: I tried the website and see that whenever you type the page 11 into nature category, the page resets page number to 1. Maybe `urllib` has some function to detect the *actual* page it's querying from? Digging into it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to *have an endless loop and break it once you don't have the "arrow right" element on the page* which would mean you are on the last page, simple and quite logical:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = 1
url = "http://www.worldofquotes.com/topic/Nature/{page}/index.html"
with requests.Session() as session:
    while True:
        response = session.get(url.format(page=page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # TODO: parse the page and collect the results

        if soup.find(class_="icon-arrow-right") is None:
            break  # last page

        page += 1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @alecxe. This is a lot faster than my version. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `requests` (avoiding redirections) and check if you get new quotes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def category_crawler():
    ''' This function will crawl through an entire category, regardless how many pages it consists of. '''

    pager = 1

    while pager < 11:
        theurl = "http://www.worldofquotes.com/topic/Art/"+str(pager)+"/index.html"
        thepage = requests.get(theurl, allow_redirects=False).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

        for link in soup.find_all('blockquote'):
            sanitized = link.find('p').text.strip()
            spantext = link.find('a')
            writer = spantext.find('span').text
            if not sanitized:
                break
            print(sanitized)
            print(writer)
            print('---------------------------------------------------------')


        pager += 1

category_crawler()
```

Comment: Thanks Nuno, but you misunderstand. I do get new quotes until the end, the script just doesn't stop at the end...

Comment: Have you tried this script? The problem is that the web redirects from the 5th - 11th page (they doesn't exist) to the 1st, and therefore you get new quotes. If you avoid this redirection you won't get new quotes and the script will finish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt.

Minor issue: put a `try-except` block in the code in case the redirection leads you somewhere that doesn't exist.

Now, the main issue: how to avoid parsing stuff you already parsed. Keep a record of urls that you have parsed. Then detect if the *actual* url from the page `urllib` is reading from (using the `geturl()` method from from `thepage`) has already been read. Worked on my Mac OSX machine.

Note: there are 10 pages in total according to what I see from the website and this method does not require prior knowledge about the page's HTML- it works in general.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def category_crawler():
    ''' This function will crawl through an entire category, regardless how many pages it consists of. '''
    urlarchive = [];
    pager = 1
    while True:
        theurl = "http://www.worldofquotes.com/topic/Nature/"+str(pager)+"/index.html"
        thepage = None;
        try:
            thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
            if thepage.geturl() in urlarchive:
                break;
            else:
                urlarchive.append(thepage.geturl());
                print(pager);
        except:
            break;
        soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

        for link in soup.findAll('blockquote'):
            sanitized = link.find('p').text.strip()
            spantext = link.find('a')
            writer = spantext.find('span').text
            print(sanitized)
            print(writer)
            print('---------------------------------------------------------')


        pager += 1

category_crawler()
```